# unable to extract correct timestamp of a directory

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, time

I am trying to get list of directories in a particular folder, which are created during a particular time( say, all files created during 11th Hour). Below is my code:

```
import time
import os
def get_information(directory):
    file_dict={}
    for i in os.listdir(directory):
        a=os.stat(os.path.join(directory,i))
        b=time.gmtime(a.st_ctime)
        newTime=b.tm_hour
        if(file_dict.has_key(newTime)):
            file_dict[newTime].append(i)
        else:
            file_dict[newTime]=[]
            file_dict[newTime].append(i)
    return file_dict
```

While i am able to see there are files created during 11th hour, but the code above is not able to extract it.

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 oamops   oamgroup     512 Aug 21 11:23 69-2181071677
drwxrwxr-x   2 oamops   oamgroup     512 Aug 21 11:23 69-2181071621
drwxrwxr-x   2 oamops   oamgroup     512 Aug 21 11:23 69-2181071661
drwxrwxr-x   2 oamops   oamgroup     512 Aug 21 11:23 69-2181071625
drwxrwxr-x   2 oamops   oamgroup     512 Aug 21 11:23 69-2181071673
drwxrwxr-x   2 oamops   oamgroup     512 Aug 21 11:23 69-2181055504
drwxrwxr-x   2 oamops   oamgroup     512 Aug 21 11:23 69-2181055500
drwxrwxr-x   2 oamops   oamgroup     512 Aug 21 11:23 69-2181055508
drwxrwxr-x   2 oamops   oamgroup     512 Aug 21 11:23 69-2181055512
drwxrwxr-x   2 oamops   oamgroup     512 Aug 21 11:23 69-2181055516
```

Another thing to note is, that there is data from 0th hour to 5th hour, and then data starts from 18th hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a filter function:

```
import os, datetime

def check_time(path):
   t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(path))
   return t.hour == 11
```

Then just filter your directories:

```
filtered = filter(check_time, os.listdir(r'my/path'))
```